# NSXMLParser error 201 when it reaches xsi:nil

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, xml-nil, nsxmlparsererrordomain

I have a NSXMLParser parsing and XML source and one of my tags is `<expire xsi:nil="true"/>`. When the parser reaches this tag, it throws an NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 201. If I remove this tag from my XML source, I get no error.

Any ideas why this is throwing an error??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `/` in the end of this tag seems to be the issue. To close it properly, try

```
<expire xsi:nil="true">
</expire>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I didn't add the URI for the namespace.
So you should define in the root element the URI for your namespace like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en">
  <entry>
    <im:name>Angry Birds Star Wars</im:name>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Where "im" is the namespace like yours "xsi".